# Kendo grid how do i auto-size an excel export row height?

Tags: excel, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a custom excel output class that I'm using to parse the grid, and in some cases replace the data in the grid with template data.  In this particular instance, the data i want to output is multi-line.  I have it working to that point but the exported sheet is one line high so you can't see lines two thru-seven in the field.
desired result:

[image: desired]

actual result:

[image: actual result]

Here's a relevant section of my code.  It's the parsing loop that applies the templates and strips html, but adds line breaks first.

```
if (me.ColumnTemplates && $.isArray(me.ColumnTemplates)) {
   for (let c = 0; c < me.ColumnTemplates.length; c++) {
       let ct = me.ColumnTemplates[c];
       if (ct.template(dr).includes("</br>")) {
           sheet.rows[r + 1].cells[ct.cellIndex - 1].wrap = true;
       }
       me.elem.innerHTML = ct.template(dr).replace(/<\/br>/g, "\n");
       sheet.rows[r + 1].cells[ct.cellIndex - 1].value = me.elem.textContent || me.elem.innerText || "";
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.  I would like to either have a setting that makes this "just work" or have a way to compute the needed height and set it manually.  Either is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to auto-size it, but you can set row height it via sheets.rows.height:

```
<script>
    var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
      sheets: [{
          rows: [{
              cells: [{ value: "this row is 100px high" }],
              height: 100
          }, {
              cells: [{ value: "this row is 200px high" }],
              height: 200
          }]
      }]
    });
</script>
```

[example found here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ooxml/workbook/configuration/sheets.rows.height)

Updating your code to utilize each  in the template html you can do something like the following:

```
if (me.ColumnTemplates && $.isArray(me.ColumnTemplates)) {
   for (let c = 0; c < me.ColumnTemplates.length; c++) {
       let ct = me.ColumnTemplates[c];
       if (ct.template(dr).includes("</br>")) {
           sheet.rows[r + 1].cells[ct.cellIndex - 1].wrap = true;
          
           sheet.rows[r + 1].height = (ct.template(dr).match(/<\/br>/g) || []).length * 20 + 20; //20 was default row height.
       }
       me.elem.innerHTML = ct.template(dr).replace(/<\/br>/g, "\n");
       sheet.rows[r + 1].cells[ct.cellIndex - 1].value = me.elem.textContent || me.elem.innerText || "";
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i knew i could size it manually.  The problem is how do i size it to show, say, 7 lines?  I don't know how tall that is in pixels.

Comment: In your code example, you're setting wrap to true whenever there is a "</br>", what if you count the number of </br> in the template and do something like row.height = row.height * (number of </br>'s) for that row? Ugly, I know, and auto-size would be awesome , I agree.

Comment: i'm testing it.  I'll let you know how it works.  It didn't occur to me to read the height it assigns for a single row.  I was trying to figure out how to determine that height.

Comment: Here's my working code.  Please add it to your answer and i'll accept it.  Strangely, It's working perfectly.  I "thought" it would be off one row.

sheet.rows[r + 1].height = (ct.template(dr).match(/<\/br>/g) || []).length * sheet.rows[r + 1].height;

Comment: @JohnLord Glad it worked out for you - I have updated the answer.

Comment: i'm accepting this answer now.  However i had to actually change my code.  I was getting inconsistent results on a different computer on reading the existing row size.  I had to assume a row height of 20.  It was undefined on a different system, presumably due to a different jquery version or kendo.

Answer (score 0):

**Set column width to auto**

> **Solution 1**
> When kendo grid bound to data source in JavaScript/jQuery

```
excelExport: function(e) {
      var columns = e.workbook.sheets[0].columns;
      columns.forEach(function(column){
        // also delete the width if it is set
        delete column.width;
        column.autoWidth = true;
      });
    }
```

[more details](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-excel-export-autofit-columns)

> **Solution 2**
> When kendo grid is taking data source from action controller not bound to data source in jQuery then add event to call a JavaScript function on excel export

```
 function exportToExcelSheetColumnWidthChange(e) {
    var columns = e.workbook.sheets[0].columns;
    columns.forEach(function (column) {
        delete column.width;
        column.autoWidth = true;
    });
};
```

Add event to the kendo grid control

```
.Events(e => e.ExcelExport("exportToExcelSheetColumnWidthChange"))
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but you answered for width, which i already knew how to control.  I was asking about height.